# Pilot briefing strip

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, ifr-navigation, cfi

Hello can you guys break this down for me?

The briefing strip says

Rwy 10 R helicopter visibility reduction below RVR 4000 NA. Is NA not authorized or Not available?

Simultaneous approach authorized .

Inop table does not apply to S-ILS 10R

Comment: what approach are you referring to?

Comment: NA = not authorized. N/A = not applicable. It’s on the abbreviations page of the Terminal Procedures Publication (TPP).

Comment: This was ILS or LOC RWY 10L FLL

Answer (score 2):

That’s a “Not Authorized” ie a RVR may not be below 4000 for helicopters flying the approach.

Simultaneous approaches authorized means that instrument approaches into runway 10L, 10C or additional parallel runways, are authorized by ATC to be flown simultaneously with the S-ILS 10R approach.

The inoperative table, i.e. the approach minimums with inoperative airport equipment are not applicable when flying an S-ILS approach.  Most likely, these are applicable to situations when one is flying a LOC approach to localizer only minimums.

Comment: The "Inop components" table refers to approach lighting systems, touchdown zone lights, etc. and will stipulate an **increase in visibility** for a particular instrument approach if a component is inop. Of course, if the approach plate states that  "Inop table does not apply to S-ILS 10R" then if the approach lights, RVR equipment, etc. is inop  an increase in minimum visibility is not necessary.  [old example only of an inop components table](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/acf/media/Presentations/19-02-RD330-Updating_INOP-Components-Table-Update.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

> Simultaneous approach authorized

Means that ATC can have aircraft flying approaches to both 10L and 10R at the same time.  ATC will have requirements on what they have to maintain as far as separation between aircraft, and those requirements can vary based on things like runway separation and radar monitoring.  For the pilot, we aren't given their whole rulebook; we're just told that they can run approaches to both runways at the same time.

If the runways were too close together, then you wouldn't have this notation and the in-trail spacing would be the same as if all aircraft were flying an approach to the same runway.

In some cases like Atlanta, where you have 8L (usually arrivals), 8R (usually departures), 9L (usually departures), 9R (usually arrivals), and 10 (both), the chart may say something like, for 9R, "Simultaneous Approach authorized 8L, 8R, and 10", meaning that they can have an approach to one of the 8's, and 9R, and 10 all at once, but not to 9R and 9L at once, since they're pretty close.

That notation doesn't spell out all the restrictions that ATC applies, but it tells you that it's okay to be on this approach and see (on TCAS) aircraft on a parallel approach with less than normal (3 NM) nose-to-tail separation.